# How do I analyze this recursive function on paper?

Tags: recursion

```
void recursive(int n) {
  if (n<=0) {
  return;
  }
printf("%d ",n);
recursive(n-2);
recursive(n-2);
printf("%d ",n);
}
```

So my question is: how do I go about determining the output of this piece of code (if we assume n=3 initially) without any tools but a pen and paper? Is there any technique for notating different levels of the recursive call, because I keep getting lost in trying to wrap my head around this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any technique for notating different levels of the recursive call

Indentation. Graph paper makes that easier. Leave the first *k* squares empty in each line to indicate you are at recursion depth *k*.

Comment: What do I write at each line? I assume I should write something like ex: 1) n=3, print, recursive(n-2)
or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to think about this as a tree of the calls. In this particular case as `int n` is passed by value you can just duplicate the descendants for the first recursive call.

When `n=3`

First n will be printed equaling `3`
Then recursive will be called with `n=1` so then it will print `1`
Then recursive will be called with `n=-1`. This will trigger the direct return statement resulting in no output.
At the end the original number is output

The above will happen twice for each original recursive call resulting in the following output.

```
3
1
1
1
1
3
```